# Want to remove Space Before and after ListView GroupHeader Xamarin Forms-iOS

Tags: listview, xamarin, space

After an each GroupHeader in listview there is space before and after. I want to remove all those spaces. This happening only iOS Simulator and Device.
Just for further information it was working properly previously but now Listview groupheader coming with space after an each row.

Below Image -This is what i want to achieve and previously it was working also as accepted [This is what i want to achieve and previously it was working also as accepted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/58Qbb.png)

This what is happening now after a every GroupHeader there is space coming only in ios. [This what is happening now after a every GroupHeader there is space coming only in ios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKLo8.png)

```
                    <Grid Padding="0,0,0,0">
                    <ListView
                        x:Name="listView"
                        Margin="0,20,0,0"
                        ios:ListView.GroupHeaderStyle="Grouped"
                        GroupDisplayBinding="{Binding GroupDetailName}"
                        IsGroupingEnabled="true"
                        SeparatorVisibility="None">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" VerticalOptions="Center">
                                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer
                                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                                NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                                                Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
                                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <Label
                                                Margin="50,10,0,10"
                                                FontSize="16"
                                                Text="{Binding GroupAppName}"
                                                VerticalOptions="Center"
                                                VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <StackLayout BackgroundColor="Red" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer
                                                CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                                NumberOfTapsRequired="1"
                                                Tapped="Groupnameclicked" />
                                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <ImageButton
                                            Margin="20,12,8,6"
                                            BackgroundColor="Red"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
                                            HeightRequest="14"
                                            Source="{Binding StateIcon}"
                                            WidthRequest="15">
                                            <!--<Image.Triggers>
                                                    <DataTrigger
                                                        Binding="{Binding Isvisible}"
                                                        TargetType="Image"
                                                        Value="True">
                                                        <Setter Property="Source" Value="arrowdownnew.png" />
                                                    </DataTrigger>
                                                </Image.Triggers>-->
                                        </ImageButton>
                                        <Label
                                            Margin="0,0,0,0"
                                            FontSize="18"
                                            HorizontalOptions="Start"
                                            Text="{Binding GroupName}"
                                            TextColor="White"
                                            VerticalOptions="Center"
                                            VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
                                    </StackLayout>

                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Custom Renderer to remove the space.

Please refer to the following code:

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(ListView),typeof(MyRenderer))]
namespace Formssss.iOS
{
public class MyRenderer : ListViewRenderer
{
    public MyRenderer()
    {
    }
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<ListView> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);
        if(Control != null)
        {
            Control.SectionHeaderTopPadding = new nfloat(0);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Below is the official documentation for custom-renderer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/custom-renderer/

Comment: I will use this and then update you. Thanks in advance

Comment: I tried adding Control.SectionHeaderTopPadding = new nfloat(0); into my code but it didn't worked. Issue is still coming.

Comment: Hi Kettan, Could you please help confirm if the provided code has been successfully executed?As I have tested on my side that the code did remove the space.If the issue still persists,could you please provide your project demo via Github?

Comment: Hi Alexander, The code is imbedded with production code hence i can not share the demo, although i did SectionHeaderTopPadding = 0 but it did not worked.  If i am increasing the SectionHeaderTopPadding  it is increasing the padding on value 0 it came back to same position as mentioned above in image.

Comment: Hi Alexander, on my demo project it is working but with my above code it is now working as expected

Comment: Update-  Control.SectionHeaderTopPadding = new nfloat(0); --This is also working but in my application it was not working. but I have updated my Xcode version to latest (13.2.1)and it resolved the issue.

Comment: Hi Kettan,that's a great news!Thanks for your update!